# Making a long function inline

Tags: c++, optimization, stl

Suppose I have a 10 line function. If I add inline keyword, let's say there is a chance of 50% that compiler will make it inline.

If I have a 2 line function, there might be 90% chance it will be inlined.

Can I split the code in 10 line function into 5 functions to make it inlined with better chances?

Comment: Don't try and beat the system. Them compiler decides what is best for you because you do not have the tools to make the correct decision (unless you happen to write inline-ing algorithms). If you want to force inlining check your compiler documentation there may be a switch to force the compiler to inline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be a reason why the compiler isn't inlining it, possibly something to look at. In addition, the function call overhead becomes less of an issue with longer functions, so inlining them may not be as important (if that's your only reason).

Splitting the function into 5 small functions will just make a mess of your code, and possibly confuse the compiler and end up with it not inlining anything. I would not recommend that.

Depending on your C++ compiler, you may be able to force it to inline the function. Visual C++ has the `__forceinline` attribute, as well as a setting for how inlining should be handled and how often it should be used in the project settings. As Tony mentions, the GCC equivalent is `__attribute__((always_inline))`.

You may also be able to use some preprocessor trickery to inline the code itself, but I would not typically recommend that.

Comment: For GCC, e.g. `inline void foo(char) __attribute__((always_inline));`

Answer (score 3):

If it makes the code more readable, go for it.  If not, trust the compiler and don't go messing up your code on the off chance that it'll help.  The compiler's a lot smarter than you think, and generally knows better than you do when inlining will help -- and when it won't, or worse, will break stuff.